# how to revoke all scopes in gapi.auth2?

Tags: google-api-js-client

Is there a way to revoke all scopes in gapi.auth2?

I am getting the scopes implicitly (and correctly) using react-google-login.

```
<GoogleLogin
 clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GGL_CLIENT_ID}
 buttonText="Login"
 onSuccess={googleResponseSuccess}
 onFailure={googleResponseFailure}
 cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
 scope={["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"]}
/>
```

which returns the correct scopes
per advise I tried to revoke using:

```
auth2.signOut().then(function () {
  auth2.disconnect();
};
```

yet a follow up login with [] scope

```
<GoogleLogin
 clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GGL_CLIENT_ID}
 buttonText="Login"
 onSuccess={googleResponseSuccess}
 onFailure={googleResponseFailure}
 cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
 scope={[]}
/>
```

still return response.tokenObj.scope.split(' ') as:

['email', 'profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'openid']

Answer (score 0):

After some digging found the answer:
[token revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke)

Strangely it involves an HTTP POST request rather than an oath client call.
For completeness pasting as is:

```
    const https = require('https');

// Build the string for the POST request
let postData = "token=" + userCredential.access_token;

// Options for POST request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server to revoke a token
let postOptions = {
  host: 'oauth2.googleapis.com',
  port: '443',
  path: '/revoke',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

// Set up the request
const postReq = https.request(postOptions, function (res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', d => {
    console.log('Response: ' + d);
  });
});

postReq.on('error', error => {
  console.log(error)
});

// Post the request with data
postReq.write(postData);
postReq.end();
```